# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions remote notification empty on App Launch

Tags: ios, notifications

I am implementing Push Notification in my app, and everything works just fine when the app is open: when a Notification is received, my method `[self processRemoteNotification:pushNotification]` fires off as expected.
Now I want the same method to be called, when the app is receiving a remote notification, when it is NOT running. 
For that, I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    NSDictionary* pushNotification =
    [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (pushNotification) {
        [self processRemoteNotification:pushNotification];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

I'm not really sure how to test this though.

What I did is

1. kill the app on the device
2. send a notification to the app
3. wait until the device displays a badge & notification
4. start the app on the device from Xcode

In the above method, I have put a break point. Somehow, the condition `if (pushNotification)` is not met, and my `[self processRemoteNotification:pushNotification]` is not fired.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the app by sliding the notification from left to right on the lock screen or from the notification centre.

Comment: That works fine indeed. However: if I'm on the springboard, and I tap the notification, the (killed) app is opened, and nothing happens

Comment: Correction: tapping the notification works fine. Opening the app by tapping the app icon doesn't trigger my method though. As far as I understand, that is expected behavior.